# Sanding/filing small patterns at an angle

Tags: sanding, plywood

I've got small patterns cut out, about 5cmx5cm, from 12mm ply wood and glued together to form 24mm thick pieces.

I need to file down the sides to get closer to the pattern (that I drew on the pieces) as well as having the sides at about 10 degrees tapered. (I'm building a mould and the 10 degrees is the release angle).

My question, as a lazy hobbyist, is, how do I sand down the edge of the ply wood at 10 degrees off square?
(I have a flat hand file, sand paper, mouse sander, table mounted disk sanding machine)

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your table mounted disk sanding machine; build top on the table sloped at 10 degrees.
This only works on convex forms.
For concave parts us a piece of wood at 10 degrees to aim your file.

Comment: I've made a 10 degree guide and it looks like it will do the job of keeping the file and or chisel.  It makes it easier, but not easy ;)

Answer (score 2):

Although it's possible to do this sanding manually I would definitely not want to attempt it myself! It would take an age and anyway I prefer not to do this kind of work entirely by sanding, because turning wood into dust is not what I took the hobby up for, but if I had to I'd want to use a belt sander (the power sander ideally suited to bulk removal, and capable of good accuracy if used with care).

Given only the tools you list I would prefer to use the file for the bulk of the work, but whether that's a good way to go is highly dependent on the file (single-cut or double, how fine, worn or not worn etc.)

Even though I'm a big fan of rasps and files and consider them under-utilised in woodworking they still make dust, and I'm a firm believer in the motto *shavings > dust*, which in this case means I would prefer to have the bulk of the shaping done prior to using a file — by paring with a chisel or carving/whittling knife (very sharp of course).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've tried the chisel (using the guide I made) and the problem is the it seems to chip out chunks in the different layers of the ply wood.  But the rasp is a good idea, which I'll investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

Having read and reread your question, I think that I now understand what you are trying to do.  One of the most inexpensive hand tools you can get is a coping saw.  Use a vice or some kind of clamp to hold the wood in place and gently make your cuts, eyeballing the ten degree angle.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I've cut out the pattern using a jigsaw (coping saw).  I'm not doing this often enough to "eyeball" it.